# Sequelize querying with encrypted fields using after* before* hooks

Tags: mysql, encryption, sequelize.js, node-crypto, sequelize-hooks

Hey there I have a question about the best way to store data encrypted in my database. I use Node.js, a MySQL database and sequelize 6.6.5 as ORM.

**Here's what I do:**

- With beforeCreate and beforeUpdate hooks I'm encrypting my data
  before storing it in the database.
- With the beforeFind hook I encrypt the condition for querying before
  doing so.
- And with afterCreate, afterUpdate and afterFind hooks I decrypt the
  data to work with it after creating updating or querying for it.

But the the querying itself raises some problems for me which I think come with the way I encrypt my data. I use the Node.js crypto module with the aes-256-cbc algorithm and a **random** IV for every encryption.
With the random IV every encryption results in a different string. That's why even if I use the beforeFind hook to encrypt my condition the query will never return any result.

```
myModel.create({myField: "someData"}); 
// with the beforeCreate hook encrypting this the database will contain something like this
// myField: "1ac4e952cf6207e5fd79630e0e82c901"


myModel.findAll({ where: { myField: "someData" } });
// The beforeFind hook encrypts this condition but as mentioned the result is not the same 
// as the encrpyted value in the database
// It will look something like this:
// { where: { myField: "e203a4e22cf654w5fd7390300ef2c2f2" } }

// Because "1ac4e952cf6207e5fd79630e0e82c901" != "e203a4e22cf654w5fd7390300ef2c2f2"
// the query results in null
```

I obviously could use the same IV to encrypt my data which then would lead to every encryption of the same source resulting in the same encrypted string but I would rather not do that if there is any other way to make it work like this.

So basically my two question are:

Is there a way to make this work with the an encryption using a random IV?
Or is there an even better way to store the data encrypted in the database?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the **random (salt)** part is exactly to prevent what you are trying to do.

I'm not sure about your use case but sometimes it's ok to encrypt without a salt (same data => same hash), sometimes (think of the user password) absolutely **not ok**.

From what you have posted I don't know where you are saving the random part, otherwise how do you decrypt the data?